# How to cut first part of a string in C#

Tags: c#, string, substring

I want to cut the first 8 characters of a string. Like this:

```
string strURL = "file:///C:\";
```

And I want to have it like:

```
string strURL = "C:\";
```

Thanks!

Comment: And... What is the problem?

Comment: This is a quick solution strURL.Substring(strURL.IndexOf("C:\"))

Comment: I don´t know how to do that.

Comment: @Ateik Thanks man this is exactly what i want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public string Substring(
    int startIndex,
)
```

for your example

```
strURL = strURL.Substring(8);
```

EDIT: I read it wrong. Corrected.

Comment: Thank you. I already have the right solution here: strURL.Substring(strURL.IndexOf("C:\"));

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get the absolute path or your URL, use :

```
 Uri address = new Uri(@"file:///C:\");
 Console.WriteLine(address.AbsolutePath);
 Console.ReadKey();
```

It will return ' C:\ '